# How to use a color picker for the canvas stroke color?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

In my basic canvas painting tool I want the user to be able to change the color of the stroke by using a color picker. So I want the `ctx.strokeStyle` to change to whatever color the user  picks on the color picker. I've managed to add the color picker to the canvas by using the `input type="color"` but I'm wondering how I can make the color of the stroke/brush in the canvas to change according to the color picked in the color picker.

So this is my canvas at the moment:

[image]

And I want the user to change the stroke color by using this:

[image]

Comment: Why cant you get its value on the event `onchange`? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Riesling/PEGS4/) is an example on jsfiddle that I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805611/event-handler-for-a-html5-color-input-element). BTW, currently there are some browsers that does not support `type=color`. For a list check this [link](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-color-element.html)

Comment: +1+ for having the tab `How to Ask` open in the browser :)

Comment: @wendelbsilva Thanks, I will try having a crack at that...

Comment: Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/KQHMA/2/ -- So I want somehow for the stroke color to be changed to whatever color the user picks using the color picker.

Comment: @user3088233 [http://jsfiddle.net/wjAdP/](http://jsfiddle.net/wjAdP/). You just need to get the color on the event `onchange` and set it to the `strokeStyle`. From your code I added the call back `change`. In this function it set the `color value` to the variable `color`. And in the `draw` method, it set the `strokeStyle`.

Comment: @wendelbsilva Thank you so much! I really appreciate it man :) I love you!

Comment: @user3088233 np. BTW, if you want a solution similar to the colorpicker shown in your picture, check markE answer. You can use both of them to make something like MSPaintBrush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the picture you posted, looks like you want a solution like markE posted in his answer. Although, in the text you mention `type="color"`. If you want to use this input you can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjAdP/) working. In this second case, just remember a lot of browser do not support it yet. Click [here](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-color-element.html) if you want to see a list of browser that support it.

Below I will try to detail what changes I did to your jsfiddle.

Firstly, you need to set a callback to the color `input`. This mean when the value of the input changes, it calls the method `change`. The function `change` is getting the `value` of the input and set in a global variable called `color`.

```
var color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
function change(e){
    color = this.value;
}
document.getElementById("color").onchange = change;
```

The other change was inside your `draw` function. Before the draw it is getting the value in the variable `color`. This way, the next time you change the color it will update the color used in the stroke.

```
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
```

With those changes, if in the future you decide to use another tool to get the color (for example, you can check the [browser](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-color-element.html) to see if it support the `input="color"` and use a different color picker in this case), you just need to set the new color in the variable `color`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of a color picker on a "tools" canvas used to set the current color (fill/stroke) on the drawing canvas:

[Javascript paint Canvas, need help re-locating buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478715/javascript-paint-canvas-need-help-re-locating-buttons/20480669#20480669)

For your "color wheel" picker, you would paint your wheel on the tools canvas and then use context.getImageData to grab the pixel color data under the mouse cursor.

```
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(mouseX,mouseY,1,1);

var data=imgData.data;

return("rgba("+data[0]+","+data[1]+","+data[2]+","+data[3]+")");
```

After the user picks their color on the tools canvas, you can use context.strokeStyle and context.fillStyle to make those colors active on the drawing canvas.

Comment: Here is my code -- http://jsfiddle.net/KQHMA/2/ Would you mind just editing that so that stroke color changes according to the color picker? I would appreciate it so so much! Thankss

Comment: +1 this solution looks similar to the color picker in the picture shown in the question

Comment: @Loktar Tell me, how is it totally different from this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ewu2p.png) he presented? Now im intrigued.

Comment: @wendelbsilva I didn't look at his picture, I just looked at the fiddle. But yes according to his image this would also be a good solution (better for cross browser like markE points out) Anyway I would take back my downvote but can't since the answer needs to be edited, I down voted in haste, a lesson that I shouldnt look at questions when busy with other tasks :P

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the value of the color input and set the `strokeStyle` to that.

## **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KQHMA/6/)**

```
var points=new Array(),
    colorInput = document.getElementById("color");

        function start(e){
          var mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
          var mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
          paint = true;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
          points[points.length]=[mouseX,mouseY];
        };

        function draw(e){

          if(paint){
             var mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
             var mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop; 
             ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
             ctx.stroke();  

             // set the value to the color input
             ctx.strokeStyle = colorInput.value;

             ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

             points[points.length]=[mouseX,mouseY];
          }

        }
        function stop(e){
          paint=false;
         var s=JSON.stringify(points);
            localStorage['lines']=s;
        }  



        var paint=false;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',start);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',draw);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',stop);
```

Comment: @markE ah crap Im sorry I didnt pay attention to the username... I wish I wouldn't have downvoted in such haste :( I cant remove it since the answer needs to be edited. Also I swear his original question didn't show the custom color picker like that. Anyway I upvoted another random answer of yours :P

Comment: heh another comment, I guess his image always did look like that, it was just a link originally so I skipped over it and just looked at the fiddle.